# JPA Query returning nulls - Composite Key with null column

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, composite-primary-key

I have a legacy database (Cobol files actually) that I am accessing using a proprietary JDBC driver with Hibernate/JPA.

The Entity has a composite primary key with 2 columns: `CODE` and `SITE`.

In the legacy data there are records for the same `CODE` that can have either a specific value for `SITE`, or there can be a record with NULL in the `SITE` column which represents 'All Sites'. The theory of this file is, if you cannot find the `CODE` for your specific `SITE` then you lookup the record with NULL in the `SITE` (the 'catch-all').

I cannot change the structure of this 'table' as it would involve rewriting large parts of the legacy Cobol system which we don't want to do. I also cannot create views of the data.

Now when I do an `em.find` with the primary composite key class containing a specific `code` and a null for `site`, then Hibernate correctly finds the matching record with the NULL value in the column - All good!

But if I try to do a query using `em.createQuery` similar to the following:

```
SELECT x FROM TareWeight x WHERE x.pk.code = 'LC2'
```

for which there are 2 records, it returns a null object in the resulting list for the record with the NULL in the `SITE` column.

If I take the SQL that Hibernate uses for this query, then the 'database' returns two records, one with the NULL site and one with a specific site. It seems that when Hibernate loads the Entities from these results, it is mapping it to a null Entity object.

So either Hibernate supports it or it doesn't. Why would the `em.find` work but not the `em.createQuery`?

I know that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15687837/jpa-composite-primary-key-with-null-value) is similar, but the answers seem to suggest that it is impossible. But clearly Hibernate can do the find correctly, so why does the query not work?

---

**EDIT:** OK, so I found a `NullableStringType` class definition on [this Hibernate JIRA Issue](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-1109) and added it to my project.

If I add a `@Type` definition on the `site` column of the PK using this type class, then I can successfully get non-null Entities back from the SELECT query, with the `site` field containing whatever String text I define as the representation of `null`.

However, it is still behaving differently. The `find` returns an Entity with the `site` field containing `null`, but the query returns an Entity with the `site` field containing "NaN" (the default representation of `null`).

It still feels like these should behave the same.

---

**UPDATE 2:** Some of you want to know specifics about the 'database' in question.

It is the Genesis RDBMS engine, written by [Trifox Inc.](http://www.trifox.com/). The data is stored in AcuCobol (now Micro Focus) Vision indexed files.

We have the configuration set to translate blank (SPACES) alphanumeric fields to NULL, hence our file records which contain spaces for the PK field are being translated to NULL. I can specifically select the appropriate record by using `WHERE site_id IS NULL`, so the RDBMS **is** treating these blank fields as an SQL NULL.

Having said all that I do not believe that this issue has anything to do with the 'database', apart from the fact that it is unusual to have PK fields being null.

What's more, if I log the SQL that Hibernate is using for both the `find` and the query, they are almost identical.

Here's the SQL for the find:

```
select tareweight0_.CODE as CODE274_0_, tareweight0_.SITE as SITE274_0_, 
       tareweight0_.WEIGHT as WEIGHT274_0_ from TARE_WEIGHT tareweight0_ 
       where tareweight0_.CODE=? and tareweight0_.SITE=?
```

And here's the SQL for the Query:

```
select tareweight0_.CODE as CODE274_, tareweight0_.SITE as SITE274_, 
       tareweight0_.WEIGHT as WEIGHT274_ from TARE_WEIGHT tareweight0_ 
       where tareweight0_.CODE=? and tareweight0_.SITE=?
```

As you can see, the only difference is the column alias names.

---

**UPDATE 3:** Here's some example data:

```
select code, site, weight from tare_weight where code like 'LC%';

 CODE   SITE    WEIGHT
 ------ ------ -------
 LC1               .81
 LC2               .83
 LC2    BEENLH     .81
 LC3              1.07
 LC3    BEENLH    1.05
 LC4              1.05
 LCH1              .91
 LCH2              .93
 LCH2   BEENLH     .91
 LCH6             1.13
 LCH6   BEENLH    1.11
```

And searching specifically for NULL:

```
select code, site, weight from tare_weight where code like 'LC%' and site IS NULL;

 CODE   SITE    WEIGHT
 ------ ------ -------
 LC1               .81
 LC2               .83
 LC3              1.07
 LC4              1.05
 LCH1              .91
 LCH2              .93
 LCH6             1.13
```

Comment: If you're comparing the find to your query, shouldn't your query's predicate also have 'x.pk.site is null'?  I know this doesn't answer your question as to why the query returns an entire null entity, but something to consider if trying to debug behavior between the two approaches.

Comment: Fair comment. So if I add the where clause `AND x.pk.site IS NULL` then I still get a single null entity in the resulting list. So they are still behaving differently, even though the SQL is now essentially the same. The point to note is that the query is finding the correct number of records, and the resulting list always contains the correct number of entries, it's just they are null if the site column is null.

Comment: What is your DBMS? Also please show some example data. Please stop using "null" when the database does not actually contain an SQL NULL or when a corresponding Java value is used in Nullable types. NULL is treated specially by SQL, as is NaN by Java. Primarily, they never compare equal to anything including themselves. It is also important to know when something is a string representation of some non-string value. It is important to understand what value is being seen by what layer and what it passes to the next layer.

Comment: What is the underlying data store / DB ???. If it is an Index / VSAM file, there is no such thing as Null; it most likely low-values (Hex zero's). There will be issues mapping the the file to a 'DB' (or it could be Hibernate issues)

Comment: @philipxy Please see my latest update. While you cannot compare two null values, you **can** select a record based on whether a column `IS NULL`.

Comment: @Bruce Please see my latest update. The 'NULL' values come from a translation of a blank (all spaces) alphanumeric field to an SQL NULL equivalent. This can be tested for using the `IS NULL` condition in the where clause.

Comment: @Philipxy LOL, there's no way I can create an MCVE without you being prepared to pay US$20,000 for a copy of the proprietary RDBMS engine. If you don't know the answer to why Hibernate behaves differently betweem the `find` and the query, then perhaps you should just move on.

Comment: @philipxy as you can see from the example data, the RDMS sees a NULL value in the column where it is blank. Without the custom user type, Hibernate returns a complete Entity with a java 'null' value in the field mapped to that column when I do a specific `find`. However, if I do a select query which is identical to the query used by Hibernate for the `find`, Hibernate returns a java null for the **whole entity**, not just the individual field. That's what I'm trying to get to the bottom of. Why does the Hibernate JPQL SELECT behave differently to the `find`?

Comment: Just because we can't run all your code doesn't mean you shouldn't show us exact input, output & code for each tool layer for your find & createQuery. (Including SQL DDL & query tree & plan.) Although since Hibernate says they don't support PKs with NULLs, that is moot.

Answer (score 8):

> "So either they support it or they don't"

**TL;DR** That expectation/feeling is unjustified. The unsupported functionality in your link (& mine below) is exactly yours. "Not supporting" it means that if you do it then Hibernate can do anything they want. You are lucky that they (seem to) return reasonable values. (Although it's just a *guess* how they are acting. You don't have a specification.) There is no reason to expect anything, let alone consistency. When behaviour is just a consequence of some unsupported case arising, any "why" is most likely just an artifact of how the code was written with other cases in mind.

---

Here is a(n old) support thread answered by the [Hibernate Team](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=961522):

Post subject: Composite key with null value for one column
PostPosted: Mon Jul 03, 2006 2:21 am

> I have table with composite primary key and I created following
>   mapping for the table.As it is possible to insert a null value for any
>   column in composite key as long as the combination of all columns is
>   Unique, I have record in teh table which has null value for V_CHAR2
>   column ( which is part of composite key ) . when I execute a query on
>   this entity I get null values for the records which are having null
>   value of V_CHAR2 column. What's wrong in my mapping and
>   implementation..

Posted: Tue Jul 11, 2006 9:09 am
Hibernate Team

> a primary key cannot be null (neither fully or partial)

Posted: Sat Jan 06, 2007 5:35 am
Hibernate Team

> sorry to disapoint you but null in primary key is not supported -
>   primarily because doing join's and comparisons will require alot of
>   painfullly stupid code that is just not needed anywhere else.....think
>   about it and you will see (e.g. how do you do a *correct* join with
>   such a table)

This is not surprising, because NULL is not allowed in a PK column in SQL. A PRIMARY KEY declaration is a synonym for UNIQUE NOT NULL. NULL is not equal to anything with the (misguided) intent that some unrecorded value is not known to be equal. (Your expectations of some kind of exception for at least some occasions of NULL in a PK *equaling* a NULL in a condition is contrary to SQL.) Given that NULL is not allowed in PK values, we can expect PK optimizations related to 1:1 mappings and to sets rather than bags of rows to assume there are no NULLs when it's convenient. One can expect that Hibernate decided to not worry about what their implementation did with cases that shouldn't arise in the SQL. Too bad they don't tell you that on compilation or execution. Hopefully it is in documentation.)

Even `find` differing from `createQuery`re NULL is not surprising. The former involves one value while the latter involves what are expected to be sets (not bags) of rows without NULLs (but aren't).

A workaround may be to not treat any column of a primary key as NULL but as the actual string of spaces in storage. (Whatever this means given your storage/DBMS/hibernate/JPA/Java stack. You haven't given us enough information to know whether your Cobol view of the database would be impeded by not mapping spaces to NULL for your JPA). With your data you can still declare a UNIQUE index on the columns.

Comment: Yes, I found that thread as well, but as I have already stated I **can** `find` the record successfully and Hibernate returns the Entity with the site field containing null. So either they support it or they don't. Why is the `find` different to the query? Your workaround is not viable. We cannot change the structure or the data in this 'table' without rewriting parts of the existing Cobol code, which we will not do. I do have a viable workaround now, which is the `NullableStringType` as mentioned above, but the behaviour is still inconsistent.

Comment: So if a man with no legs wanted to ride a bicycle, would you scoff at him and tell him that bicycles don't support legless people? Or would you try to offer him a solution to meet his desires? I would really hate to be one of your customers to be perpetually told that No, they can't have that functionality they wanted because the software doesn't support it. I guess that's why our company has been around and successful for almost 30 years. Because we never say that something is impossible. It's called [Kiwi Can Do](http://www.nzherald.co.nz/nz/news/article.cfm?c_id=1&objectid=11188987).

Comment: There seems to be a misunderstanding. I'm trying to clear up misconceptions & answer the question actually asked. (A workaround is evoked, but that's not the question. If the real question is for a workaround, please make that clear.) (And in your title too for more views.) Your preface/premise: "So either Hibernate supports it or it doesn't." Unsound. Q: "Why would the em.find work but not the em.createQuery?" A: find *doesn't* work per SQL (since NULL<>NULL) and anyway either can do anything because the contract is violated. (We don't know exactly when @Type/NullableStringType works either.)