# JPA Embeddeble PK and nullable field

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, hibernate-mapping

I have a table called "Attributes" which has a PK of 3 fields which can be null. In this case Style_no is not null but item_no and size_no are null.

Is it possible to have a Embeddeble PK where fields can be null?

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ATTRIBUTE")
public class Attribute {

    @EmbeddedId
    private AttributePK attrPK;
    ...

    @Embeddable
    public static class AttributePK implements Serializable{

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -2976341677484364274L;

        @Column(name="STYLE_NO", nullable=true)
        protected String styleNo;

        @Column(name="ITEM_NO", nullable=true)
        protected String itemNo;

        @Column(name="SIZE_NO", nullable=true)
        protected String sizeNo;
    ...
```

When i try to reference over one field e.g. style_no the result amount is 0.

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true, mappedBy="attrPK.styleNo")
@MapKey(name="attrPK.name")
public Map<String,Attribute> attributesX;
```

OR

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
@JoinColumn(name="STYLE_NO", referencedColumnName="STYLE_NO")
private List<Attribute> attributes;
```

When i remove item_no and size_no as pk im receiving a valid result.

Edit: 
To make my question more specific. Is per JPA guideline or "common sense" not allowed to use nullable fields for EmbeddebedId? If not, what annotions or logic do i need to add to make it work without adding another PK?
Once filling the nullable field in the PK with values. The result is corrct.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386040/whats-wrong-with-nullable-columns-in-composite-primary-keys)
Seems, that answer that (NULL == NULL) -> false is about your question.

Comment: Thank you, for the link. But as the comments below mentioned correctly its not that satisfing. E.g. from JPA it not allowed to use an Id on a field which can be null. But I cannot find the same restriction for EmbeddedId. All i need is if there is a workaround without adding another artificial Id or a link to a source which says that nullable field in a EmbeddedId are not allowed.

Answer (score 3):

Since [you must not use null in your PK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70909/hibernate-mapping-a-composite-key-with-null-values), this is what you should do:

1. Add a [surrogate primary key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key).
2. You can still achieve the uniqueness constraint and the default PK index with a parial index (in PostgreSQL):

   CREATE UNIQUE INDEX style_item_size_idx ON my_table (Style_no, item_no, size_no) WHERE (item_no IS NOT NULL AND size_no IS NOT NULL);

Comment: Thank you but, I was explicit asking a solution wihtout adding another id - "..it work without adding another PK..".

Comment: I understand, only that this is a DB limitation you need to be aware of.

Comment: Sure, my exmaple above is just to find out if Hibernate, as an extra layer, can avoid such DB specific borders. No real use case.

Comment: I always choose Hibernate for [these reasons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23930151/is-it-a-good-idea-to-use-hibernate-for-representing-table-relations/23932324#23932324), otherwise I would use only [JOOQ](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.3/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/select-statement/window-clause/) which has great querying abilities.

Answer (score 0):

Usually a compound pk is not allowed to have null-values in the database.

Technically we would say: Why not, a `null` can be a value too.

The DB-Analyst would ask: Ok, if i sort 1,2,3,4,`null`,5. Would you say `null` is before 1 or after 5?

Therefore PostgreSQL, Oracle, MySQL will not support null-values in compound primary keys.

Comment: 1) For the order i would say that the DB can decide it on its own. Technically its just important that it is defined anywhere. 2) Yes, a PK contraint is not allowed. For a UNIQUE constrain it is allowed but it still doesnt work with hibernate.

Comment: @MortalFool you are right, i added the 2. word from last: `primary` to clear the difference between keys and primarykeys.

Answer (score 0):

JPA guideline or "common sense" not allowed to use nullable fields for EmbeddebedId? If not, what annotions or logic do i need to add to make it work without adding another PK?

answer is as below

```
@EmbeddedId
private AttributePK attrPK;
```

does not allow the primary key to be null.

so to make it happen use another annotation like below

```
@IdClass(AttributePK.class)
 private AttributePK attrPK;
```

Comment: Thank you, ill try to validate it tomorrow.

Comment: The IdClass has an `@Target({ElementType.TYPE})`, how can you put it on a field???